# cloudwatch alarm for redshift queryduration

Tags: amazon-redshift, amazon-cloudwatch

I have below cloudwatch alarm defined in CF template for altering me on queries running for 30 mins or more.

```
    Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
    Properties: 
      AlarmName: !Sub "awsredshift-${RSClusterName}-QueryDuration"
      AlarmDescription: Redshift QueryDuration Alarm
      Namespace: AWS/Redshift
      MetricName: QueryDuration
      Dimensions: 
        - Name: ClusterIdentifier
          Value: !Ref RSClusterName
        - Name: latency
          Value: long
      ActionsEnabled: true
      AlarmActions: 
        - !Ref TopicARN
      OKActions: 
        - !Ref TopicARN
      ComparisonOperator: GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold
      DatapointsToAlarm: 1
      EvaluationPeriods: 1
      Period: 300
      Statistic: Average
      Threshold: 1800000000
      TreatMissingData: missing
```

But its activating the alarms when there are no queries running that long, am I missing something?

Also is there any way to customize the alarms to put logic in them, I would like to get the SQL text of the query which is running longer. Is there any way to do this via cloudwatch alarms? If not whats the best way to do it - probably lambda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative approach you could use is to implement a [Query Monitoring Rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/cm-c-wlm-query-monitoring-rules.html) in Redshift for queries where `query_execution_time` exceeds 30 minutes and uses the `log` action to record the details of the query in the [STL_WLM_RULE_ACTION](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_WLM_RULE_ACTION.html) table.

This captures all the info you might need about long running queries but doesn't create an alert. However, it's easy enough to set something up yourself to do that, Amazon provide an example solution using Lambda [here](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/tree/master/src/QMRNotificationUtility).

Comment: Thanks Nathan, btw do you see any issue with the current cloudwatch alarm I have. Any idea why its getting triggered even when queries are not running for 30 mins. The way I created, is it taking average of all the queries in a span of 5 mins?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Cloudwatch Alams but at guess your Alarm is looking at the *average* duration of *all queries* on a cluster over the specified period and comparing to a threshold of 30 minutes duration. It's not looking at specific queries so, assuming you want to know which specific queries are taking longer than that, I don't think you can achieve that with CloudWatch.